# With VLOOKUP, is there another option for COL_INDEX_NUM?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

The current code:

```
VLOOKUP("*"& SPID &"*",Carriers,6,FALSE)
```

I currently have 26 numbered COL_INDEX_NUMs on a dynamic spreadsheet undergoing a few updates. If I need to add more columns in between columns, I currently have to renumber all of my VLOOKUP formulas to match.

On my main sheet, I have it built easily with the first cell of data is col_index_num 2 all the way through 26. When I need to add another cell in between, I have to readjust all of these formulas individually and audit to make sure they all match.

Is there a way this can be dynamic as well, or is this just a function that needs better planning?

The only thing I found online was sites that mentioned VBA coding which I won't be able to incorporate.

Many thanks!

EDIT: I did include the code but really it was more of a question regarding VLOOKUP in general. I posted to make sure everyone understood my question related where the 6 is located.

Resolution:

```
=INDEX(Carriers,MATCH(SPID,INDEX(Carriers,0,1),0),MATCH(A3,INDEX(Data!1:1,1,0),0))
```

This formula simplifies what I was doing. VLOOKUP was doing what I had wanted it to do but to modify on a dynamic and new document, caused more work than necessary. By using the INDEX formula as the answer I selected below, this allows the formula to keep track of the column when it moves around without me needing to stop and adjust.

Carriers = all of my data on a sheet named Data minus the headers.
Data!1:1 = My headers on the same sheet.
SPID = a 4 digit alpha-numeric to call the information.

I tested by moving a column and adding another as well. It kept the information. To test to make sure it wasn't a fluke, I had created another sheet to see the difference. The old sheet errored while the new sheet showed the correct information.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: You could use match formula to find the correct column index: Instead of `6`, you would put something like `MATCH("ColumnTitle",1:1,0)`.  Where "ColumnTitle is the label in row 1.  Another Note: if your search range does not start in column A then the full row reference will need to change to start with the same column as the search range ; `$B$1:$AZ$1`

Comment: Instead of hard-coding `6` in the Vlookup formula, use a cell reference. Create another worksheet (hidden, if so desired) with your column mapping on it.  Then, you should be able to update the "mapping" sheet only, and all formula would refer to the values on that sheet, whenever they change, the result of the formula would change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an INDEX formula instead of VLOOKUP.

E.g. `=INDEX(Carriers,MATCH("*" & SPID & "*",$A:$A,0),MATCH("MyColumnHeader",1:1,0))`

- The first argument will be your reference table - you can insert extra columns if you want,
- The second argument is the column you are searching your SPID number for (this doesn't have to be the first column) - this will return the row number.
- the third argument is the column header you are searching for - this will return the column number.

A good reference site is:  http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions03.html

**Edit:**
As an update, the formula above reference column A and row 1 of the worksheet and not the Carriers range.
`=INDEX(Carriers,MATCH("*SPID*",INDEX(Carriers,0,1),0),MATCH("MyColumnHeader",INDEX(Carriers,1,0),0))`
This formula reference column 1 of Carriers using `INDEX(Carriers,0,1)` and row 1 using `INDEX(Carriers,1,0)`

Comment: To @Darren Bartrup-Cook, thanks! At first look, I thought it would be too complicated to comprehend but using Excel's built in tools to explain each field, I realized it wasn't that complicated.

Comment: Took me a while before I was confident with the INDEX way of doing it.  Very versatile though, so worth the effort.